# How to access through a path rather than just in current directory?

Tags: python

I have written a function which reads in an excel file and manipulates it. Obviously the .py file has to be in the same directory as the excel file. Is there a way to enter the path of the file so I can leave the script in the same place?

Comment: the .py file can be in a different directory to the excel file - what is the code you are using to open the file?

Comment: I am using xlrd. So xlrd.open_workbook('filename')

Comment: Just replace 'filename' with '/path/to/filename'. Or 'C:\\Path\\to\\filename' on Windows. You can use os.join to pick the correct separator if it needs to be cross platform.

Comment: @Thomas I tried this before and it says invalid mode ('rb') or filename:

Comment: Sounds like you haven't got the path quite right. Are you using Windows? Make sure you're doubling all the \s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Obviously the .py file has to be in
>   the same directory as the excel file.

I don't understand "obviously"

> Is there a way to enter the path of
>   the file so I can leave the script in
>   the same place?

Yes, just type it in.

From the [xlrd documentation](http://ttps://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#__init__.open_workbook-function):

```
open_workbook(filename=None, etc etc etc)

    Open a spreadsheet file for data extraction.

    filename
        The path to the spreadsheet file to be opened.
```

Snippet of script (presumes you are not hard-coding paths in your scripts):

```
import sys
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook(sys.argv[1])
```

Running this in a Windows "Command Prompt" window:

```
python c:\myscripts\demo_script.py d:\datafiles\foo.xls
```

Same principles apply to Linux, OS X, etc.

Also, this advice is quite independent of what software you are feeding the filename or filepath.

**About hard-coding file paths in Python scripts on Windows:**

In ascending order of preferability:

- Use backslashes: `"c:\testdata\new.xls"` ... the `\t` will be interpreted as a TAB character. The `\n` will be interpreted as a newline. Fail.
- Escape your backslashes: `"c:\\testdata\\new.xls"` ... Yuk.
- Use a raw string: `r"c:\testdata\new.xls"`
- Use forward slashes: `"c:/testdata/new.xls"` ... yes, it works, when fed to open().
- Don't do it ... see script example above.

Comment: I swear, I have tried and am trying this exact thing...it even autocompletes the path for me. Not sure what the problem is

Comment: @Kosig: Show exactly what you have in your script.

Comment: Well oddly enough it worked when I entered c:/path/filename instead of backslashes

Comment: Right. well in my actual code I will be using a gui to select path so I won't be hardcoding it. I just was testing and kept running in to this problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kosig: Please disambiguate your last comment; surely you can express "very bad" or "very good" without having to use words like that.

Comment: @John Machin Didn't mean to offend.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
os.chdir('/my/new/path')
```

You can change the current working directory by using `os.chdir`.

Another way would be to reference the excel file (however you are opening it) by an absolute path.

Comment: The example is very unfortunate. Excel files are binary and should be opened in binary mode. In any case, open(....).read() might be what a parser of Excel files might do at some stage, but it's not something that the OP would want to do, nor be encouraged to do. All you need to say is to use an absolute (or relative!) path.